# Why Zeldris has the power of the demon king?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the manga it's mentioned that Zeldris has the power of the demong king. And I believe in the anime too. What does this mean? Why Zeldris has the power of the demong king?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demon King is ruler of Purgatory. 3000 years back, during the fighting their bodies were destroyed and in order to retrieve his body. So he grant Zeldris the power of demon king but in reality he is making Zeldris a container for his vessel to grow his body.

Answer (score 2):

#### Because he's basically Demon King's right hand

In the Drole and Gloxinia's flashbacks, already after Meliodas's treachery, Zeldris is a) Meliodas's successor as the only other Demon King's child b) supposedly the new Ten Commandments leader and b) "fixer" as mentioned by Gowther, when Demon King realizes that Gowther got out of his prison and Zeldris was sent to get him back. The Demon King's power that Zeldris has is simply granted by Demon King for Zeldris to do his bidding